# Keep selected items in UISearchController (like Snapchat/Messenger/Whatsapp) in swift code

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, search, uisearchcontroller

I was wondering if there was an easy way to keep the selected names in the Search Controller without interfering with the search results at any time, sort of like when creating snapchat group chats for example.

So far I have a tableview with a designated UISearchController and I store all selected names in an array.

Here is what I was hoping to achieve (with the example of snapchat):
[image]

Comment: you want to create custom or looking for any library ?

Comment: I would rather create my own custom one but if using a library makes things way easier I would certainly do it

Comment: Check these libraries https://github.com/whitesmith/WSTagsField, https://github.com/pikachu987/Tags

Comment: Is there any way to add the "tags" to a UISearchController rather than a UITextField or UIView ?